# why my app release apk size is too small and is not installing app on my device in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to install my flutter apk (release). I tried `flutter clean`, rebuild the apk again and again, still no luck. I have reinstalled Android SDK build tools, and still nothing.

I am thinking maybe my `build.gradle` files might have issues. Not sure. If you think that this might be the case, do tell me to upload these files.

One thing that I have noticed is that the size of my app is really small. Like I made another build for another app, and size for that was 52 Mb. But for this app, the size is 34 mb, which is strange, as this app has much much more features, files and some more packages than the previous one, still size is lower.

Edit:
Here are my build logs -

```
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.6.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Font asset "fa-solid-900.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 394628 to 1016 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3760 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a5088802b6f46e5ec62d896acf2d7a63/transformed/jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-21.3.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/java.
com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_analytics_ktx_granule.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/160eda7973cb4ebe4234c10624c5dafa/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fedea92b5de0d297a02ca58993f63ff7/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6316eb034674692e6ae9113cc60ed6df/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.       
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ff60ad1d7f44863c45fee8616a6b91e1/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-live
data-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ac720bb0b1958e1e224a27c8794b5bc/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-IN
F/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ab2a0b8e5a17e379cedd6805d76bcfc0/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/dc5b1733b493234eecba2c1dfa5bfc01/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/63e2116ea4c0438fddb59ef1fce1db0b/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.1/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar
!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6993ed60322c40dde1138584ce1b8594/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/M
ETA-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/
META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          127.1s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (32.5MB).
```

I build the app using -

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk --release

Comment: We need more infos, give us your build error, how do you build the apk, etc.

Comment: @OzanTaskiran edited the post, please do check if it helps

Comment: Ah, nvm. I understood it wrong, so you can build your apk but you cant install it? Do you see any error message when installing the apk? Any popup/message? Do you have already a version installed on your device?

Comment: It displays this message: "app not installed as package appears to be invalid"

Comment: @OzanTaskiran my problem is solved. Thanks for your support. Do you think that my answer has correct explanation, please do tell

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved.

I made these changes in my app/build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug{
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            //shrinkResources false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
//        debug{
//            shrinkResources false
//        }
    }
```

Because, I don't have key.properties file, app could not find configs for release, hence might be throwing the error. But, as soon as I set that to `signingConfigs.debug`, it  started working well.